# How can I show and update a Text in a window (e. g. like on a digital watch) in Python?

Tags: python, window, clock

I'm trying to build a countup clock with a raspberry pi. Now I'm thinking about, how I can show the counter (yeras:months:days) on a screen. So how can I generate a window, which shows the counter and updates itself (e. g. every hour). My idea is to use it as a decoration, so it shouln't be nessessary to interact with the shown.

That's my code so far:

```
import time

now = time.localtime()
hour=now.tm_hour
minute=now.tm_min
summer=now.tm_isdst
#print("Tag:", day)
#print("Monat:", month)
#print("Jahr:", year)


while True:
    time.sleep(3600.0)
    day=7
    month=4
    year=now.tm_year
    if month<4:
        j=year-2020
    elif month==4:
        if day<4:
            j=year-2020
        else:
            j=year-2019
    else:
        j=year-2019


    if month<4:
        m=month+7
    elif month==4:
        if day<7:
            m=month+7
        elif day>=7:
            m=0
        else:
            m=month-4
    else:
        m=month-4




    if day<7:
        t=day+24
    elif day==7:
        t=0
    else:
        t=day-7
    print(j , ":" , m , ":" , t)
```

Comment: Hi Klien. You can use a UI library to show the time on a separate window. And update the time on the UI at regular intervals of time. You might want to checkout Tkinter

Comment: Hello, yes I've seen tkinter, I experimented with it, but I thought I can only update the window with closing the window and opening a new one. Can I change the text in the box without closing the window?

Comment: You can Klien. Try it out.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will try it out this evening :)

Answer (score 0):

look into the python [curses module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) or one of the wrappers around it (i.e. [blessings](https://github.com/erikrose/blessings)) which is a little easier to use. This will allow you to create a screen in the terminal and refresh the screen every so often, this would be every second in your case. This would allow you to open a terminal in the pi run it and just leave it.

However a much easier solution would be to just keep calling `time.ctime()` and clearing the screen and refreshing it, but if you want to get some practice with curses so you can do stuff with it in the future go for it.